# Difference between proguard-rules.pro and proguard.cfg

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, proguard

I am learning and implementing proguard for very first time. I have seen some examples and add following code in `proguard-rules.pro` file, but there is also 1 more file named `proguard.cfg`.

I have tried to google this but unable to understand the difference between `proguard.cfg` and `proguard-rules.pro` file.

I have added following in `proguard-rules.pro` file but what should i add in `proguard.cfg` file

```
#---------------TEST

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keep class com.conviva.**
-dontwarn com.conviva.**

-keep class com.loopj.android.http.**
-keep class org.apache.http.**
-keep class rx.internal.util.**
-keep class com.algolia.search.**

-dontwarn com.loopj.android.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.**
-dontwarn com.algolia.search.**

-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}


#---------------TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your proguard commands inside **proguard-rules.pro**. You can find this file inside your project as

```
YourProject -> app -> src-> proguard-rules.pro
```

Inside another file `proguard.cfg` you have to-do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, so proguard.cfg should be empty then?